# CLion show me an error when I use a new signal-slot connect function with Qt5

Tags: qt5, clion

I'm developing Qt5 application, but when I use a new signal-slot connect function, CLion will show me error, "Incompatible pointer types 'const char *' and 'void(*)(bool)'". I'm sure the lib is Qt5. How should I do to solve the problem.
This is my code(OS X 10.11.3).

```
// KSMainWindow.cpp
#include "KSMainWindow.h"
#include <QMenuBar>
#include <QToolBar>
#include <QDebug>

KSMainWindow::KSMainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent) {
    setWindowTitle(tr("KSText"));

    openAction = new QAction(tr("&Open..."), this);
    saveAction = new QAction(tr("&Save..."), this);

    QMenu *file = menuBar()->addMenu(tr("&File"));
    file->addAction(openAction);
    file->addAction(saveAction);

    textEdit = new QTextEdit(this);
    setCentralWidget(textEdit);

    connect(openAction, &QAction::triggered, this, &KSMainWindow::openFile);
    connect(saveAction, &QAction::triggered, this, &KSMainWindow::saveFile);
}

KSMainWindow::~KSMainWindow() {
    delete openAction;
    delete saveAction;
    delete textEdit;
}

void KSMainWindow::openFile() {
    qDebug() << "Open";
}

void KSMainWindow::saveFile() {
    qDebug() << "Save";
}
```

CLion hope the &QAction::triggered convert to const char *.

This is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(demo8)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ./bin)
find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets Core Gui)
aux_source_directory(./src SRC_LIST)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} MACOSX_BUNDLE ${SRC_LIST})
qt5_use_modules(${PROJECT_NAME} Widgets Core Gui)
```

Comment: Is it only the Clion code analysis that says that, or it is a build error when you actually build the project?

Comment: Thanks for you, just the CLion says that. I can build my code and run.

Comment: Then it's a bug in Clion. Clion is still pretty new, and skill has a few kinks like that to fix. Add a ticket to the [Clion bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/CPP) so they learn about it.

Comment: You are right, the problem is a bug. QT5 depend on variadic templates support, but now the CLion doesn't support the character. Thanks your help.